# Discord bot hosting. SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've played around with coding discord bots before, just found Discord Bot Maker and it seems really good. I've now tried to find a host for it. Everything seems to be setup fine, however the following is displayed when I run "bot.js" Any help would be appreciated.

```
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] /bot.js:301
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] if (channel?.messages.cache.has(packet.d.message_id)) return;
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] ^
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
14.07 11:51:47 [Bot] at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

Comment: What's your nodejs version?

Comment: Should of added that before, sorry. 12.16.3.

Comment: No problem :) The problem is your node version doesn't know what a nullish coalescing operator (`?.`) is. discord.js v13 requires node 16.6 or higher so that's why it throws errors like these.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll update the version. Although I think I may of tried that it threw a different error but I'll post an update. Thanks

Comment: That completely worked. I didn't try 16.6.0 before. I tried a newer Node version that I don't think DMB2.0 supports. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your version of node.js is too deprecated to use discord.js, [this feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator#relationship_with_the_optional_chaining_operator) has been added in later node.js versions so upgrading your node.js will fix the issue